# JSON-LD loaded with JavaScript not recognized?

Tags: javascript, seo, schema.org, google-search-console

in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data), it is stated that JSON-LD can also be integrated via Javascript.

Based on this info, I've built a script that does just that.

Several days have passed and based on the search console, the site has been crawled multiple times since then.
But when I look at the console for structured data, I'm still told that there are none on the page.

From the test [tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool), I get the information that the data is available and error-free.

Must the crawl process have gone through several times before it is detected?
Is it not possible despite the documentation?

Here an expamle of our company JSON-LD:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context":"http://schema.org",
    "@type":"Organization",
    "name":"Name of our organization",
    "url":"our url",
    "logo":"link to our logo",
    "description": "short description",
    "address":{
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "addressLocality":"City and country",
      "postalCode":"postalcode",
      "streetAddress":"street"
    },
    "email":"our main email",
    "telephone":"phonenumber",
    "faxNumber":"fax number",
    "sameAs":[
      "https://www.facebook.com/our",
      "https://twitter.com/our",
      "https://www.instagram.com/our"
    ]
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Sounds like you just need to wait on Google to do their thing.  As far as I can tell, there's no technical problem with what you've posted.

Comment: you think they don't get it right on the first crawl?

Comment: Who knows, it might take multiple passes, a certain amount of traffic, could be anything.  If the test tool shows it works... you've likely done what you need to do.

Comment: I've seen live rich snippets show before that report showed anything. Like most GSC reports, you have to wait. Also, the initial crawl is not rendered, that happens later, so expect another delay because of that.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath could you just make an answer out of this? In the end is was on the 6th crawl. (the site get craweld quite often)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen live rich snippets show before that report showed anything. Like most GSC reports, you have to wait. Also, the initial crawl is not rendered, that happens later, so expect another delay because of that.